# How do I make my subtraction calculate the correct answer?

Tags: c, subtraction

This program requires the user to input numbers (maximum of 10), but once the user enters a negative integer the program breaks and proceeds to calculate the sum, difference, product, and quotient of all the numbers entered. I think I got everything right except for the subtraction part because it always shows the wrong answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
double number, sum = 0.0, difference = 0.0, product = 1, quotient = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  printf("Enter n%d: ", i);
  scanf("%lf", &number);

  // if the user enters a negative number, break the loop
  if (number < 0.0) {
     break;
  }

  sum += number; // sum = sum + number;
  difference -= number;
  product *= number;
  quotient = number / quotient;
}

 printf("Sum = %.2lf", sum);
 printf("\nDifference = %.2lf", difference);
 printf("\nProduct = %.2lf", product);
 printf("\nQuotient = %.2lf", quotient);

 return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is an example of the code working with user input]

Comment: What is wrong with subtraction result? What is expected?

Comment: Please do not post text output as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: You entered 1,2,3 and the resulting difference was -6. Why is that wrong? What is the correct answer expected to be?

Comment: the answer would either be -4 or 0, depending on the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you mean by difference and I think that you should pay attention to the fact that we use difference when comparing only 2 numbers.
if you want to know what your program is doing it is simply adding the negative values of the inputs. that is why difference is negative of sum :
difference= -(1)-(2)-(3)=-6

Comment: ohhh. I now understand why it does that. Thank you so much! So it is not possible to subtract multiple numbers?

Comment: do you mean some thing like   1-2+3=2    or  -1+2-3=-2   ? @s0mi